# How to add SortDescriptor to GridViewDataColumn's parent RadGridView

Tags: silverlight, sorting, inheritance, telerik, radgridview

I'm extending GridViewDataColumn and I want to implement some custom sorting for it. So I need to add SortDesccriptor to the parent RadGridView of my GridViewDataColumn.
There's not much documentation and the sources are not available. How can I get the column's parent GridView so that I can add SortDescriptors to it?

I'm using RadControls for Silverlight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you have an instance of a GridViewDataColumn and you want to get the parent RadGridView? Does the following not work?

```
public RadGridView GetGridView() 
{
    return this.DataControl as RadGridView;
}
```